# Size limit for the return value of a jQuery or JavaScript ajax get method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser, get

When I use an ajax GET method, is there a size limit for the return value?

If so, is this limit due to JavaScript/jQuery? To the browser? to the server?

I have seen older articles (5+ years old) that seem to indicate that there was a size limit, but I couldn't find any recent information on this topic.

Comment: As far as I know there is a request size limit. That is, some browsers don't allow to invoke URL longer than 2K chars... But for the response I'm not sure and it would real surprise for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP protocol does not limit the size of any response, and neither does jQuery itself. So theoretically speaking, you can make your GET response as big as you want.

In practice, however, there *are* some constraints: the web server may have a maximum response size (especially when you're caching entire responses), server code may need intermediate processing steps that require additional storage, the client needs to store the response data somewhere before processing it, the javascript implementation on the browser may have extra memory constraints (you don't want a rogue script eating up all your physical RAM: that would be a severe security problem). How much exactly is too much is pretty hard to pinpoint though: a few megabytes are probably OK, a terabyte certainly isn't.

Note that the request method is pretty uninteresting in this context; the above issues are just as valid for responses to POST requests, or any other HTTP verb.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a limit.  Its dependent upon architecture and available memory. On a x86_64 machine with 2G and a 64bit build, it will fail with InternalError: script stack space quota is exhausted however on a x86_64 with 4G and a 64bit build it will pass.

So it ultimately depends on the machine that is running and hosting the script to efficiently serve the request.

If you receive an InternalError Script Stack message it just means you need upgraded hardware to run the request(s).

Ways to "control" this are to do whats called "throttling".  See another stack for reference on this:
[How to rate-limit ajax requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031501/how-to-rate-limit-ajax-requests)