# Limit how many times an event listener can trigger every second

Tags: javascript

I'm playing with the Gamepad API - in particular the axes using the joysticks on a controller. The position of these updates a lot and often - as such, the event that I'm listening for (movement on the sticks) also happens a lot. Is there any way to limit it happening to, say, 25 times a second in order to reduce lag?

Comment: What you are looking for is called *throttling*. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031501/how-to-rate-limit-ajax-requests/.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't limit the rate at which JavaScript events are triggered, but your event handler could opt to do nothing on some calls. Here is an example using `mousemove` (I don't know which Gamepad API you're talking about):

```
var lastMove = 0;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
    // do nothing if last move was less than 40 ms ago
    if(Date.now() - lastMove > 40) {
        // Do stuff
        lastMove = Date.now();
    } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jk3Qh/

Comment: A simple solution, but you could miss the "last" event which is important in some scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, where you check how often your event is called in a 1 second interval and whether or not you process it. Code sample, rough outline of what I was thinking (no gaurantee (like that spelling)).

```
function process_event() {
var curr = new Date().getTime();
if ((curr - timeObj.last) < 1000) { //One Second 
     if (timeObj.counter > 25) {
        for (var x=0;x<timeObj.times;x++) {
             if ((curr - timeObj.times[x]) >= 1000) {
                   timeObj.times.splice(x, 1);
                   timeObj.counter -= 1;
             }
        }
     }
     else { 
         timeObj.counter += 1;
         timeObj.times[timeObj.times.length()-1] = curr;
     }
}
else {
    timeObj.counter = 0;
    timeObj.times = [];
}
if (timeObj.counter > 25) {
    return False
 }  
 else {
   return True
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a variable that increments every time the event listener activates. Make it so that the function the event listener outputs only occurs when the variable is below 25.