# Add delay between two functions declenched at scroll

Tags: javascript, function, scroll

I found code which runs a function when I scroll. And it works fine. But the problem is that it runs the function too many times per millisecond; can someone help me to add a function which allows me to choose the number of milliseconds between two function calls? Thanks :)

```
var runOnScroll =  function(evt) {
  console.log("hello");
};
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".div2");
elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);
elements.forEach(function(element) {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", runOnScroll, {passive: true});
});
```

Comment: You add a `scroll` listener multiple times. Notice that you run `addEventListener` inside a `.forEach` callback.

Comment: Also, you can check this post to add a time limit to a listener https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667010/limit-how-many-times-an-event-listener-can-trigger-every-second

Comment: Did you mean `element.addEventListener`?

Comment: Thank you all ! 
I was really talking about window.addEventListener^^