# Implementing Infinite Scroll in existing website

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, scroll, infinite-scroll

We are trying to implement infinite scroll in our existing website. Currently we have a image 'click for more' and it makes a ajax call to a method GetArticlesFromNextSection(true) which returns data which we append in #sectionArticles. And this works perfect.

Now we are trying to make it automatic as when user reaches at the end it should make a call to GetArticlesFromNextSection(true) method to load next chunk. Here is what we are using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            $('#lnkShowMore1').trigger('click'); //click image or
            //GetArticlesFromNextSection(true);
        }
    });
</script>
```

The problem with above code is, it makes continuous call to method GetArticlesFromNextSection(true) until no data left to load from database. It should make a single call to method GetArticlesFromNextSection(true) and stop and when user tries to scroll again, it should next chunk.

How to make this possible?

**EDIT**

I used flag but it loads just one time and never again. This is not infinite loop, it should load another chunk again when user reaches end. This is what I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var is_loading = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() -300) {
            if (is_loading) {
                return;
            }
            is_loading = true;
            //$('div#more').show();
            $('#lnkShowMore1').trigger('click'); //click image or
            //GetArticlesFromNextSection(true);
            //$('div#more').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the answers for [How to rate-limit ajax requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031501/how-to-rate-limit-ajax-requests)

You can either include and use Underscore's _.throttle() in your script, or take a look at how they implement it and adapt into your code instead of including the whole library for a single purpose.

**EDIT:**

Using Underscore, your code might look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).scroll(_.throttle(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        $('#lnkShowMore1').trigger('click'); 
    }
}, 1000));
```

... which should rate-limit the requests to once every second.

Comment: You may also want to check out http://underscorejs.org/#debounce and see which fits what you're looking for better

Comment: I never used underscore before, this is how I used. added the reference of <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js" ></script> and then your suggested code, but it does nothing.

Comment: There was a typo in my code (I forgot a '.' between '_' and 'throttle' when attempting to call the function. I edited my answer with this correction.

Comment: Note that my answer rate-limits the triggering of a click on your button and you may have to experiment with the timeout (currently set to 1000). @cesare's answer is another you might consider. The difference is that theirs will let the event handler fire whenever the ajax call has finished round-tripping, whereas mine prevents excessive calls using a flag and a timeout. You may want to try both and see which is more desirable.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag that check if the content is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (!isLoading && $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
    isLoading = true;    
    $('#lnkShowMore1').trigger('click'); //click image or
        //GetArticlesFromNextSection(true);
    }
});
</script>
```

And inside Ajax callback sets

```
isLoading = false;
```

Comment: I used flag but it loads just one time and never again. This is not infinite loop, it should load another chunk again when user reaches end. check edit above.

Comment: I think you have to set is_loading to false when the new content is appended at the document.

Comment: If I'm adding is_loading = false after new data appended, it again starts making continuous call. no help.

Comment: when the new data appended, the height of document have to be higher, so in theory, the if condition have to be false, i suggest you to try to debug with firebug what is the value of "$(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()"